# Replace the href to something else using jQuery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is the HTML i have and i want to change the href attribute from http://google.com to something else, please note that this link should not be changed http://google.com/home/inner_links. I cannot edit the html so looking for a solution using jQuery or Javascript. Thanks.

```
<div class="branding">
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://">
<div class="main-menu">
    <ul><li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: What issue are you having changing the `href` of the elements?

Comment: Please show us what you have tried so far

Comment: I cannot edit the html. Looking for a solution using jQuery or javascript.

Comment: _"I cannot edit the html"_ How will you be able to edit the `href` attribute?

Comment: @guest271314 um by JavaScript.... like OP wants

Comment: @epascarello _"um by JavaScript.... like OP wants"_ How can OP edit `html` to include `<script>` tag?

Comment: i want to change the href attribute on page load so should be done using jquery or javascript

Comment: @guest271314 Because he can have a javascript file already referenced?

Comment: If you are not able to edit `html` how can you edit `html` to include `<script>` tag?

Comment: @guest271314 Give up already... OP can run JavaScript, move on.

Comment: @epascarello Refuse to adopt that phrase. Sought clarity as to situation. The `html` at Question is invalid. That should be changed first. Interesting that was overlooked in favor of OP's ability, or apparrent freedom to change an `href` at invalid `html`.

Comment: epascarello  because I have a seperate javascript file which i can edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Problems with the code fragment

First off, it is not a full document but a code fragment, as such it doesn't include appropiate headers. We can disregard this understanding that the provided code belongs to a larger document.

The following problems are present in such code fragment:

- The `img` tags require a non-empty `src` attribute and a `alt` attribute.
- The `a` tags require a valid url value in their `href` attribute.
- There doens't seem to be a closing tag for `<a href="http://">`
- And finally thig thing that doesn't make sense `<li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links">`

Now, this is beyond the question, but given that you have the following fragment:

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <ul><li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

We can see that you have closing `li` and `ul` tags. So I would expect that you were trying to do as follows:

```
<div class="main-menu">
    <ul><li><a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div>
```

---

## Solution

The code I'm suggesting to use to edit the `href` values is the following:

```
$('.branding').find('img').parent().attr('href', 'newhref');
```

That is selecting the parents of all the img that are inside elements with class "branding", and setting the href attribute of them.

### Demo with original code fragment

```js
$('.branding').find('img').parent().attr('href', 'newhref');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="branding">
  <a href="http://google.com">
<img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
<img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://">
<div class="main-menu">
<ul><li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

### Demo with the code fragment and suggested fixes

```js
$('.branding').find('img').parent().attr('href', 'newhref');
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html><head><title>demo</title><script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script></head>
<div class="branding">
  <a href="http://google.com">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" class="preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/" alt="" class="preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://example.com">link</a>
<div class="main-menu">
<ul><li><a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links">link</a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Notes: In addition to the fixes, I have create a complete document from the fragment, set the title to "demo", used lorempixel for the images, set the invalid url to `http://example.com` and added the text "link" to the anchors to ease the demo.

Comment: The `html` is invalid

Comment: @guest271314 there is no such thing as invalid html Edit: besides this is not code review

Comment: @Teraot _"there is no such thing as invalid html"_ Have not previously read this at `html` documentations. fwiw, see https://validator.w3.org/

Comment: @guest271314 the word "invalid" is not longer present in the standard for html5. fwiw https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/

Comment: @guest271314  this is just a sample html. Am asking to replace the href.

Comment: @Theraot [1.10.2. Syntax errors](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#syntax-errors) , [1.10.3. Restrictions on content models and on attribute values](https://www.w3.org/TR/html/introduction.html#restrictions-on-content-models-and-on-attribute-values)

Comment: @guest271314 ok, I give that I haven't read HTML 5.1 which is the one you link.

Comment: You can type `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<div class="branding">
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://">
<div class="main-menu">
    <ul><li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div>
</div>` at link above to view result.

Comment: @guest271314 the linked validator is for HTML 4 - but whatever I'll comply.

Comment: You can set the document type to `html5` https://validator.w3.org/#validate_by_input

Comment: @Theraot  _"So I would expect that you were trying to do as follows:"_ If accurate,there is still the issue described by OP at comment _"I cannot edit the html."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39736399/replace-the-href-to-something-else-using-jquery-or-javascript/39736608?noredirect=1#comment66770759_39736399 ; which is beyond the scope of the Question.

Comment: @guest271314 perhaps, but I no longer care.

Answer (score 1):

jquery:

```
$('.branding a').attr('href', YOUR VALUE)
```

or

```
$('a[href="http://google.com"]').attr('href', YOUR VALUE)
```

Comment: I think this solution will replace all the href attributes in the branding div from google.com to YOUR VALUE. I want just the first two href attributes to be replaced not all. Thanks

Comment: The second solution will only replace links with an `href` attribute that is "http://google.com"

Comment: Are neither of those things what you were asking for? Either to replace all straight up "http://www.google.com" links, or all the links in the branding div? If not, can you please be a little more specific?

Answer (score 1):

The `html` at Question is invalid.

```
<div class="branding"> <!-- 1) where is closing tag for this `DIV` element? -->
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me"/>
  </a>
  <a href="http://">
<div class="main-menu"><!-- 2) where is closing tag for this `DIV` element? -->
    <!-- `UL` is not permitted child of `A` element -->
    <!-- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a -->
    <ul><li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links"></a></li></ul>
</div><!-- is this closing `DIV` tag for 1) or 2) ? -->
```

That should be changed before changing the `href` at the invalid `html`. If you cannot change `html` yourself, you should ask whomever supplied the `html` why it is delivered invalid; and ask that it be changed to valid `html` before proceeding.

Then adjust `href` of `<a>` elements.

Comment: Note also, the opening `<li>` tag is missing closing `>`

Comment: It is bad html, but this is not XML where a misplaced tag invalidates the document. In fact, the browsers will make sense of it besides its defects, and we finally have consistent rules to do that in html5 - also, this is not code review. You are not answering the question.

Comment: that's the sample code -- using jquery you can on run time change the DOM elements.. so let not get into if user has pasted the correct code.. he is asking for how to replace the href -

Comment: Really? Ignore invalid `html`?  `Element name li<a cannot be represented as XML 1.0.` , `Error: Element li<a not allowed as child of element ul in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)` , `Error: End tag a violates nesting rules.` , `Fatal Error: Cannot recover after last error. Any further errors will be ignored.` .  would be first item to attend to if _"I cannot edit the html."_ is accurate.

Comment: This is just a sample html.

Comment: @sonu769 Well, the sample should be valid `html`, yes?

Answer (score 0):

jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").parent().attr("href", some url);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here a sample code- I had a similar requirement in my project.. you can change based on your need.

Note: alert() - is for demo purpose only.

```js
$(document).ready(function(e) {
var currentUrl= $("a").attr('href');
 newEditUrl = currentUrl.replace("http://google.com", "http://google.com/home/inner_links");
 alert(newEditUrl);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="branding">
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://google.com">
    <img class=" preload-me" />
  </a>
  <a href="http://">
    <div class="main-menu">
      <ul>
        <li<a href="http://google.com/home/inner_links">
  </a>
  </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: The `html` is invalid

Comment: I tried to provide the example for how to replace the href url as per the question asked using jQuery and I think thats the intention of user as well..

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
 function changeHref(){
    document.getElementsByTagName("a").href="Someplace.com";
 }
```

Also, which link do you want to change specifically? Or do you want to change all of them?